# Which chain replacement to use for Cube Aim Race?

Tags: chain, replacement

Bike is "Cube Aim Race", 29 inch wheels. My chain is so dirty and got rusty, I am bothered to clean it. I actually put a lot of effort into cleaning it, and now I am considering to REPLACE IT. Which chain replacement could I use (it is 3x8 speeds bike)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All 8-speed chains are basically the same. Whatever your local bike shop has in stock will work fine.

Comment: Just that. On top of replacing the chain it would be worth assessing the drivetrain's overall state and potentially swap out other worn parts, too. Poor maintenance (no offense) often goes along with other parts wearing out quickly, especially chainring and cassette. You can indeed just put a new chain on but it will wear out out even quicker than in normally would, at least the 6/7/8-speed chain from Shimano isn't the most long-living component out there (but cheap, I'll give it that).